# The if statement is redundant in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, return, conditional-statements

I am getting a lightbulb on NetBeans saying "The if statement is redundant"

I want to know how these two are equal to one another

```
public boolean isVowel(char in)
{
    char temp = Character.toLowerCase(in);

    if (temp == 'a' || temp == 'e' || temp == 'i' || temp == 'o' || temp == 'u')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
public boolean isVowel(char in)
{
    char temp = Character.toLowerCase(in);

    return temp == 'a' || temp == 'e' || temp == 'i' || temp == 'o' || temp == 'u';
}
```

I can see how it would return true if one of the vowels matches with temp. However, I am not seeing how it would return false. Would it simply just return false if none of the conditions are met?

Solved: I was looking at the problem the wrong way. For it to return false, each conditional statement would have to be false. Ideally it would return false if the return statement was equivalent to:

```
return false || false || false || false || false;
```

and true if any one condition is met

```
return false || false || false || false || true;
```

Thanks you guys, it really helped.

Comment: Well yes, because the result of the expression `temp == 'a' || temp == 'e' || temp == 'i' || temp == 'o' || temp == 'u'` would be `false`...

Comment: Ah I see now. If it were to return false, each condition would have to be equal to false. I was looking at the problem a wrong way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two statements are identical.

```
int x = #; //user input
if (x==1) {  //any condition resulting in a true or false
    return true;
} else {
     return false;
}
```

and

```
return (x==1); //same thing, returning true if true, false if false;
```

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
(temp == 'a' || temp == 'e' || temp == 'i' || temp == 'o' || temp == 'u')
```

calculates a boolean value. An if-statement tests this value. So instead of testing this expression in the ireturning the boolean value in the if/else-clause you can just return it.

Edit you can just prove if your char is a vowel? 
Do it this way:

```
public boolean isVowel(char in) {

    return "aeiou".indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(in)) < 0;
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this? What is "z" suppose to be?

Comment: I improved my answer .

Answer (score 0):

The two are indeed identical (and the `if` statement is redundant) and here's why.

The `==` is an equality operator, which means that, if the left side matches the right side, it evaluates to `true`, otherwise it evaluates to `false`. The `||` is a conditional operator, meaning that, if the equality on the left hand side evaluates to `false`, it will check the right side to see if it evaluates to `true` (or, if left side evaluates to `true`, then the expression will evaluate to `true`, called `short-circuiting`). If all of them evaluate to `false`, then the entire expression will evaluate to `false`.

Therefore, the `if` statement as you have it essentially turns into:

```
if(<expression>==true) { //in the case that the conditional evaluates to true
    return true;
}
else { //in the case the conditional evaluates to false
    return false;
}
```

So, that can just be reduced down to expression, since it will evaluate to a `boolean` anyways.

```
return <expression> //will be true if true, false if false
```

[There's more on this in the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Answer (score 0):

boolean isNumeric(char cc){
//begin  // test if cc is numeric
        return (
                  (cc == '0')
                | (cc == '1')
                | (cc == '2')
                | (cc == '3')
                | (cc == '4')
                | (cc == '5')
                | (cc == '6')
                | (cc == '7')
                | (cc == '8')
                | (cc == '9') );
}    // isNumeric